# PHP if function joomla no work

Tags: php, joomla

Hello everyone and thank you in advance that I will answer. I have this problem, I want to see the second page where I find a link that takes me home page blog if in other categories.

I developed this little code:

```
<div class="componentheading<?php echo $this->params->get('pageclass_sfx')?>">
<?php $link_address = "http://testjoomla0315.altervista.org/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&Itemid=53" ?>
<?php $homeblog = "Blog" ?>
<?php $doc = JFactory::getDocument(); ?>
<?php $page_title = $doc->getTitle(); ?>
<?php echo $page_title; ?>
<?php if ($page_title != $homeblog) ?>
<?php echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>Home Blog</a>"; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_title')); ?>
```

Unfortunately although not error the result is the same, or as if what I wrote was invisible. In homepage obviously sees the home page link (and that is the rule I)

Comment: Why open and close php tag on every line???

Comment: there's errors, they're just hidden, check the php error logs, or set `display_errors = on` in php.ini, and make sure `error_reporting=E_ALL`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a colon at the end of if statement.
Change

```
if ($page_title != $homeblog)
```

To

```
if ($page_title != $homeblog):
```

Also dont use `<?php` and `?>` every line. You can have the code like this

```
<div class="componentheading<?php echo $this->params->get('pageclass_sfx')?>">
<?php 
$link_address = "http://testjoomla0315.altervista.org/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&Itemid=53";
$homeblog = "Blog"; 
$doc = JFactory::getDocument(); 
$page_title = $doc->getTitle(); 
echo $page_title; 
if ($page_title != $homeblog):
echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>Home Blog</a>"; 
endif; 
echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_title')); 
?>
```